# SQL SUM on case when not equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

[image]

I should be getting 3 returned values with 1, but on my sum case statement (last one, the when seems to not be working with the OR's to produce 3, it returns 7 with random values.

Any Help on this

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ReworkCode.CodeNum != 4 
      OR ReworkCode.CodeNum != 5 
      OR ReworkCode.CodeNum != 6 
      OR ReworkCode.CodeNum != 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberRejectedByOther
```

my other case's work fine it seems.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need ands instead of "or's"  as you have it pretty much every line should result in 1.  For example.  Say the value is 3.  IT's not equal to 4 or 5 or 6 or 7.  So it's 1.  Now lets say it's 5.  It's not equal to 4.  So it will be one.  Doesn't seem like your case would really do anything but return "1".

Comment: [Please don't post data and code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please read [ask] in [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!=` and using `Or`s.... that's must ugly to maintain and think though. Try to figure out how to avoid the `or`'s or the `!=`

I think you want and's not ors...

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ReworkCode.CodeNum != 4 
      AND ReworkCode.CodeNum != 5 
      AND ReworkCode.CodeNum != 6 
      AND ReworkCode.CodeNum != 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberRejectedByOther
```

Or use:  (assuming your goal is to have anything that isn't 4,5,6,7 or null be 1.)

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ReworkCode.CodeNum not in (4,5,6,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberRejectedByOther
```

But I'm not 100% sure what you're after so neither of these may produce the desired result.